# OpenCV Lucas Kanade optical flow

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, tracking, opticalflow

I am working ona code where i have to find the trajectories of all the corner points that i am interested in. So, for the same, i used LKPyr Optical flow, which uses the corner points of the previous image and finds them in the current image. I am using the optical flow frame by frame, that is, frame 1 and 2, then 2 and 3. So, i thought that frame 2 corner features i found in the previous iteration would be the current features for the optical flow, but that is not the case, the points change everytime i do Good Features to Track, the problem is, for trajectory points, i need to track the current points and add the new ones when they come, and when the old points are about to lose, i should get the status=0, so that i can track points one by one. Is there a way to do so? Is there a way to know when each point ends in the video, so that i could track the trajectory? Would changing the flag in the call to cvLKpyrOpticalFlow help in getting a continuous flow?

```
    cvGoodFeaturesToTrack ( imgGrayscale, imgEigen, imgTemp, corners_img, &corner_count, 0.01, 5.0, 0, 3, 0.4 );

    cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK( imgGrayscale, nxtimgGrayscale, pyr_img, pyr_nxtimg, corners_img, corners_nxtimg, corner_count, cvSize ( win_size, win_size ), 5, status, track_error, IterCriteria, NULL);
```

This is the block of code that i am running to get the optical flow.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9702540/769220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run cvGoodFeturesToTrack only in the "first" (or "reference") frame of the sequence you are tracking, then cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK only in the subsequent frames.

The former routine identifies in the reference frame pixels and patches that have "high contrast" (in a well-defined sense of the expression), and therefore are likely to be more easily trackable. The latter routine actually does the tracking, matching the reference features to nearby locations in the subsequent frames, so to identify their new locations. When it succeeds it sets the corresponding elements in the status vector to 1. These features in the subsequent frames may or may not be "good features to track" for the frame itself, because there may other image regions that have higher contrast. No matter, for most applications you only want to keep tracking the "good features" detected in the reference frame.

Since tracking will normally fail for some of the features, after several frames you may find out that there are no (or not enough) "live"-tracked features left. At this point you could run another pass of "good features" detection to replenish the set.

Comment: Thanks for a thought out reply. But see, if i get just one set of initial good features to track and keep following them, then, the result is a bit vague. It gives a status 1 even for the negative values of points of the next feature. And in my case, i need to get the trajectory points of these features, so, i need a pattern of recognition for the features, which i am unable to generate. Do you have any clues regarding that? I need something that updates my current features as new objects come in the frames.