# CalcOpticalFlowLK camera motion c++

Tags: c++, opencv

this time i would know how can i calculate for each frame the camera motion in term of x and y pixel coordinates, i've googled and i've found that CalcOpticalFlowLK can do this.
I'm not expert in opencv and i'm asking your help!
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes OpenCV can do this. You should follow the tutorials on the site below to start and then attempt the CalcOpticalFlowLK implementation yourself. If you get stuck post your specific problem here (with a code sample) and I'd be glad to help.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ie/2010/09/opencv-basics.html

Then Look at

[OpenCV tracking using optical flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701276/opencv-tracking-using-optical-flow)

Comment: i've tried looking to lkdemo.cpp on the sample, it takes frames from webcam -->VideoCapture cap;
when i try to change with CvCapture* cap=cvCaptureFromFile("C:\cropped.avi"); it gives me an error because capturefromfile return an iplimage instead of a cv::mat, than i tried  with VideoCapture cap("C:\cropped.avi"); but it keeps opening the webcam...
anyway the sample let me to choose a number of point on the window, can i track those point with coordinates?
sorry for bad english and thank u all!

Comment: I'd open this up as a new question. That way more people than just me will notice it. Rather than using preselected co-ordinates I'd use the GoodFeaturesToTrack which will automatically select these points. I have edited my answer above to point you to a sample.

Comment: thank you! anyway i finally open that .avi that i need to process, i set needToInit = true that initialize a series of points in all the video, now the final thing i have to do is to find the pixel coord of those point and to calculate the motion.
If someone know how to do that i will be very thankful!
Thank you all!

Comment: Surely i don't understand something...i have points[0] and points[1] vector in which there are x and y coord of the points, how can i calculate their differences from frame to frame? i don't know how to access the x and the y of each point... 
Thank you!