# OpenCV : Object detection and tracking based on feature detection

Tags: c++, opencv, implementation, tracking, video-processing

I have just ventured into computer vision and trying to demystify various intricacies of it. I am trying to augment the kalman filter with a surf feature detector. But I do not understand how to call and use the kalman method after the homography and bounded rectangle has been constructed on the detected frame using surf features. I have detected the features and extracted the keypoints using a reference image after comparing with  the incoming frames. Then I used the flann matcher.

Now, is it feasible to use the kalman filter since I want to track the motion and get the predicted motion. I have searched a lot but have not found that surf features can be used with kalman filter. All I am getting are suggestions to use cvBlobs for tracking. But, theoretically kalman filters are used for tracking purposes. However, I am confused since the several implementations of video based tracking using surf shows that surf can be used for tracking in itself. But my question is

- If kalman filter cannot be used with surf, then how do I implement the moments to get the coordinate measurement values as I need the information for motion prediction.
- can surf be used with kalman filter for tracking and if yes how to implement it after the object has been detected and bounded with a rectangle using the following code.

  Example : the object to be tracked [image: book1.png] . Some frames [image: frame1] [image: rame2]

  /* Object Detection and recognition from video*/

  int main()
      {
         Mat object = imread( "book1.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE  );

  ```
  if( !object.data )
  {
      std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
      return -1;
  }

  //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
  int minHessian = 500;

  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
  std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

  detector.detect( object, kp_object );

  //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
  Mat des_object;

  extractor.compute( object, kp_object, des_object );

  FlannBasedMatcher matcher;        

  namedWindow("Good Matches");
  namedWindow("Tracking");

  std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

  //Get the corners from the object
  obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
  obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( object.cols, 0 );
  obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( object.cols, object.rows );
  obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, object.rows );

  char key = 'a';
  int framecount = 0;
  VideoCapture cap("booksvideo.avi");

  for(; ;)
  {
      Mat frame;
      cap >> frame;
      imshow("Good Matches", frame);


      Mat des_image, img_matches;
      std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
      std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
      std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
      std::vector<Point2f> obj;
      std::vector<Point2f> scene;
      std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
      Mat H;
      Mat image;

      //cvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

      detector.detect( image, kp_image );
      extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );

      matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

      //THIS  LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
      for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) 
      {
          if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][4].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
          {
              good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
          }
      }

      //Draw only "good" matches
      drawMatches( object, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

      if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
      {
          for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
          {
              //Get the keypoints from the good matches
              obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
              scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
          }

          H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

          perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

          //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )
          line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
          line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
          line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
          line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

      }

      //Show detected matches
      imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
      for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
      { 
          printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i,    good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); 
      }

      waitKey(0);
  ```

  }

  return 0;

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the combination of feature matching and filtering that you are describing. One idea I had is to keep track of the center of mass (and size) with a kalman filter and use that information to mask out the exterior region before running the feature matching on the next frame. I'm not sure what your constraints are, but you might consider a template matching or camshift-type tracking that could also use a kalman filter for helping with search.

Comment: Ok,so how do I use camshift with surf?I found this code http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ca/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html which uses color values. However, surf here works on gray scale images.So,even if I use gray scale then how do I implement camshift after the bounded rectangles object is detected using surf. I shall really appreciate if you can put a code snippet since I do not know how to calculate the centroid and work with camshift and surf.

Comment: I also found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701276/opencv-tracking-using-optical-flow/9702540#comment13031247_9702540 but I guess it does not use surf. So, I was thinking if it is possible to combine surf with https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/motempl.c?rev=1429 but then this is in C ! If I change the surf images from Mat to IplImage, then what should go in the function call of update_mhi( IplImage* img, IplImage* dst, int diff_threshold ) and where should I be calling update_mhi() in the surf module. Please help.

Comment: The main objective is that I need to locate the coordinates of the detected object which I think can be done using moments. I do not know how to augment moment with surf feature detection so that the predicted motion can be obtained.

Comment: Hi Shreya. We have talked about a lot of different approaches in this thread. If you could show us an example object that you want to track and give us some example frames that you would want to track it in, we could narrow down the approach to fit your needs.

Comment: I have uploaded the image of object to be tracked and 2 sample frames.So, if I can get the centroid of the object and then it will be possible to get the trajectory of the tracked motion or any other scheme. Thank you.

Comment: Tracking a simple planar object like this would benefit from a combined approach. Take a look at this research work regarding FERNS:

Comment: I did not get the link regarding FERNS. But could you anyways put up a code to demonstrate, which will work for any program in general, how to determine the moments in C++ and use the predictors or the update_mhi method.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted that comment. The link is here: http://cvlab.epfl.ch/software/ferns/index.php. It uses a combined approach by using template matching and FERNS for re-initialization (you could use SURF). The template tracking "can be done much faster than detection but is less reliable and needs  initialization and re-initialization in case of failure." If you need the motion information, then you could keep track of the center-of-mass. If speed is not a concern, just use SURF in every frame. If needed, the kalman filter could still work the way I suggested in my original post.