# Blob position comparison across several video frames

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

Goal is to detect whether an object/s(can be multiple) is stationary in a ROI for a period of time (Application: Blocking the zebra lane detection). So it means obeserving each blob with respect to time t

- Input = Video file

So, let's say the pedestrian crossing lane is the ROI. Background subtraction happens inside ROI only, then each blob(vehicle) will be observed separately for time t if they have been motionless there.

What I'm thinking is getting the position of the blob at frame 1 and frame n (time threshold) and check if the position is the same. But this must be applied on each blob assuming there are multiple blobs. So a loop is involved here to process each blob one by one. But what about processing each blob by getting its position at frame 1 and frame n, then compare if it's the same(if so then it has been motionless for time t therefore it's "blocking"). Then move on to the next blob.

My logic written on java code:

```
 //assuming "blobs" is an arraylist containing all the blobs in the image
   int initialPosition = 0, finalPosition = 0;
   static int violatorCount=0;
 for(int i=0; i<blobs.size(); i++){ //iterate to each blob to process them separately
     initialPosition = blobs.get(i).getPosition();
     for(int j=0; j<=timeThreshold; j++){
        if(blobs.get(i) == null){ //if blob is no longer existing on frame j
             break;
        }
        finalPosition = blobs.get(i).getPosition();
     }
     if(initialPosition == finalPosition){
        violatorCount++;
     }
  //output count on top-right part of window
 }
```

Can you share guys the logic on how to implement the goal/idea in either Matlab or OpenCV?

Optical Flow is an option thanks to PSchn. Any other options I can consider

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). You could yous the [OpenCV implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html). Pass your points to `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` along with the next image (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701276/opencv-tracking-using-optical-flow)). Then you could check for the distance between to points and dicide what to do.

I dont know if it works, just an idea.

Comment: I'll check on it bro

Comment: Do that and post your results ;)